# Extjs 4.4 - grid move to last row and select last cell (same as excel control + end )

Tags: extjs

I am using extjs 4.4. I have the requirement to scroll to the last row of the grid and select the last cell. Same as excel sheet Control + end key combination.

I could not track down any option for the same.

It would be great if some one resolved this issue.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

this will jump to the end:

```
var count = grid.getStore().count();
grid.getView().focusRow(count - 1);
```